# Continuously polling $.ajax request issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout, iife

I'm having an issue with a continuously polling $.ajax request. The issue I'm running in to is how to have it execute immediately first, and then execute on the interval set in the setTimeout call.

Code example:

http://jsbin.com/doneka/3/

```js
myObj = {};

var output = '';
var items = '';
myObj.displayItems = function() {
 console.log('displayItems ran');
 output = '';
 $.each(items, function(index, val) {
   output += '<li>' + val.player.firstName + ' ' + val.player.lastName + '</li>';
 });
 $('#content').html(output);

};

$(document).ready(function() {
 (function loadData() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('loadData ran....');
  return  $.ajax({
   url: '//jsbin.com/xinixa/1.json',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   success: function(data) {
    items = data.apiResults[0].league.season.draft.rounds[0].picks;
    loadData();
    myObj.displayItems();
   },
  });
 }, 3000);
 })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I refactor to have the setTimeout call inside the function, I get errors. If I make the function not self executing, I get errors as well.

Comment: Please include your code in the question; if your link dies, what use will the question be to future readers with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're using "refactor" here the way I understand it, but restructuring your code is going to help a lot in diagnosing the problem. Deeply nested functions like you've got are rarely necessary, and nearly always confusing. Here's a quick & dirty refactor to remove nesting. I'm not sure if it actually accomplishes your goal, but it does execute, without errors, continuously. [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/koxeje/2/edit?html,js,console,output):

```
var myObj = {};
var output = '';
var items = '';

myObj.displayItems = function() {
  console.log('displayItems ran');
  output = '';
  $.each(items, function(index, val) {
    output += '<li>' + val.player.firstName + ' ' + val.player.lastName + '</li>';
  });
  $('#content').html(output);

};

var loadData = function() {
  setTimeout(makeAjaxRequest, 3000);
};

var makeAjaxRequest = function() {
  console.log('makeAjaxRequest running');
  return    $.ajax({
    url: '//jsbin.com/xinixa/1.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: successHandler,
  });
};

var successHandler = function(data) {
  items = data.apiResults[0].league.season.draft.rounds[0].picks;
  loadData();
  myObj.displayItems();
};

$(document).ready(loadData);
```

A couple more areas for improvement:

- Remove the globally-saved state in `output` and `items`. `output` could easily be refactored into state on the `myObj` object, and `items` should be a parameter to your `displayItems()` function.
- While you're at it, rename `myObj` :)
- I'm not sure whether `setTimeout` is the correct function to use here; if you really want something that repeats every 3 seconds, why not use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead?

Comment: From what I've read, setTimeout is the preferred method to use over setInterval, because with setInterval the requests can get backed up. And using myObj was only for this example. The real code uses a better namespace.

Comment: Like the refactor, but the solution still suffers from the issue of not executing immediately on ready, due to the setTimeout wrapped makeAjaxRequest.

Comment: Execute `makeAjaxRequest` inside the ready handler, followed by `loadData`. It still allows you to separate out functions logically and into unit testable chunks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then this should work for you.  See it [here](http://jsbin.com/fixezuqove/1/)

```
myObj = {};

var output = '';
var items = '';
myObj.displayItems = function () {
    console.log('displayItems ran');
    output = '';
    $.each(items, function (index, val) {
        output += '<li>' + val.player.firstName + ' ' + val.player.lastName + '</li>';
    });
    $('#content').html(output);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    (function loadData() {
        console.log('loadData ran....');
        $.ajax({
            url: '//jsbin.com/xinixa/1.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                items = data.apiResults[0].league.season.draft.rounds[0].picks;
                myObj.displayItems();
                setTimeout(loadData, 10000);
            },
        });
    })();
});
```

The only part I changed was in your loadData function.  The method is still immediately invoking, but I moved the `window.setTimeout()` into the success callback (I changed the timeout to 10s for testing).  This sets the timeout after the previous successful callback which effectively sets up polling.

If you watch the console, you can see that `loadData()` executes immediately, and each subsequent call executes 10 seconds after the previous call.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.